# Using createResolver() in twisted

Tags: python, dns, twisted, reverse-proxy, hosts

I have a simple proxy script in twisted, and I want the script to read from `examplefile` instead of `/etc/hosts`:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import proxy, server
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.names.client import createResolver

createResolver(hosts='/root/examplefile')
site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('www.example.com', 80, ''.encode("utf-8")))
reactor.listenTCP(80, site)
reactor.run()
```

When I run the script, the `createResolver()` function just gets ignored. I'm not sure how to implement the `createResolver()` function to my script. Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the reactor [docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorPluggableResolver.html), the IReactorPluggableResolver provides an `installResolver` method (implemented in ReactorBase)

Not tested, but I am guessing it is something like:

```
reactor.installResolver(createResolver(hosts='/root/exampleFile'))
```

Comment: hmm.. so far, when I tried it, it didn't work and just made my script timeout, but that definitely put me in the right direction thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is busted in this example. You call createResolver and ignored it's return value which is the resolver that will read the specified file. Twisted does not magically store the resolver when called. You understanding Programming  return values from functions etc.

You also need to pass a byte string for the domain ie prepend it with a `b`

```
b'www.example.com'
```